# Is it possible to do this with Power Query

Tags: powerquery

good afternoon, I have a problem with a query in Power Query, I am making this query to a server and within the code there is a value that must be changing every month (green box (127)). It will be possible to change this value from an Excel cell as a parameter, and that this parameter is part of the code (M language) in Power Query ?

[codigo completo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlcsZ.png)
[codigo detalle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZrys.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please include (relevant) code snippets as text in your question, rather than screenshot images.

Answer (score 0):

Put your parameter value into a cell, and assign a named range to this cell - e.g. `MyParameter`

Now you can reference this named range in your Power Query, and include it in your query string:

```
MyParameter = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MyParameter"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Sql.Database("MyServer", "CAMPANAS", [Query="SELECT * FROM [CAMPANAS].[dbo].[CTO] ct WHERE ct.Refresco = " & Text.From(MyParameter)]),
```

Comment: Very kind of you to answer, I will do what you say.